# Export Stata misstable summarize

Tags: export, latex, stata

I want to report missing values in a nice table (latex).
So is there a way to export the results from `misstable summarize` in the same/similar format as displayed?

**Example code:**

```
webuse studentsurvey, clear
misstable summarize
```

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/latex/ and/or run `search latex`.

Comment: hi refp16 I know that and use it. If you get the result for misstable summarize in latex give me pls an example b/c I wasn't able to do that. thanks

Comment: `outtex` is an user-written program that generates latex code.

Answer (score 3):

There is a package by Stata that creates LaTeX code in the Stata Journal style. It´s called -sjlatex-. This allows you to transfer Stata output to a Tex document just as it appears in your output window. There is some documentation here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/latex/verbatim.htm. To install I typed `search sjlatex` and followed the links.
Then you can run something like:

```
webuse studentsurvey, clear

sjlog using my_missings_file
misstable summarize
sjlog close

sjlog type my_missings_file.log.tex
```

The Latex code will appear in the output window and will be saved in the respective file. I have no Latex available at the moment, so I couldn't test the Latex output.